# python shorter code to get list value

Tags: python, list, loops

```
year=[1,2,3,5,4,5,5] 
name=["alex","tom","amy","mary","peter","david","tim"]
maxyear=([i for i, x in enumerate(year) if x == max(year)])
```

I want these code below shorter,wanna write in one line only,like I defiened the maxyear list.

```
oldername=[]
for i in maxyear:
 oldername.append(name[i])
```

Comment: Your `name` variable assignation does not work.

Comment: You have a syntax error at line 3: `max()` is not closed

Comment: What you wanna do is to use "list comprehension", read about it, how to use it. No point to giving you result, if you won't know how it works anyway. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put the code on one line you can simply do:

```
oldername = [name[i] for i in maxyear]
```

The correct syntax for this should be (with spaces!):

```
year = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5] 
name = ["alex", "tom", "amy", "mary", "peter", "david", "tim"]
maxyear = ([i for i, x in enumerate(year) if x == max(year)])

oldername = [name[i] for i in maxyear]
```

For the sake of good practice, it may be worth taking the 'max(year)' out of the 'for statement' and storing it as a variable. This saves performing the max calculation every time.

Comment: `max(year)` : calling max func with every iteration is not a good practice, you can store max of year in 1 variable and then use it, it will save your time and performance

Comment: In something like Python in a small program it will really make no difference to speed, but I get your point - it is bad practice to do this. I'll add a note to the answer